# SignalR won't work properly inside Windows Service in comparison with Client Version

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-services, signalr

Objective: I want to send notifications to my customers in certain operations, such as when they loged in. To say in more detail, i wanna show the notification to employer that says {{x}} employe just loged in and clearly all the Authorisation codes are ready and works.

Current State: I opened another asp.net mvc web project(let say signal project) in my solutions and inside signal project i wrote my signalr codes that send notification to users according  to their authorizations.*(ClassName : Hub)*

**My client/signalr work flow**

1. List item
2. user logs in, i check his/her authorizations.
3. To her/his authorizations i assign them in to groups
4. and send notifications to employers(which they have they own group)

At this state every thing is fine and works.
But i want to convert this signal project to a windows service.So i created one.

Problem: Windows Service is working but the notifications that should be send to certain groups won't go(in my case employers won t see any notifications).

Analyze:So i review my codes and debuged with log4net library and checked the windows event log

**Tested/Debuged/Confirmed Steps**

1. Groups Creating works
2. Loged in Customer assigning to groups works
3. Send notification to employers group **WON'T work**(code below)

   `Clients.Group("Employers", Context.ConnectionId).Send("Some Context");`

So i created a method that sends notification to ALL loged in users and strangely it works
all my users including employers and employees are sees notifications.

In brief, using signalr inside asp.net mvc project, i can send notification to my users which in a specific group but while using windows service i can send notification to all my users but i can t send notification to my users which in a specific group.

I can share code if needed?
Any insights, thoughts, ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Revising -

In the method are you setting the hub context?

```
IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Hub>();

(do some stuff)

hubContext.Clients.Group("Employers").Send("Some Context");
```

If you are can you show some code?

Comment: i used the Clients.Group("Employers", Context.ConnectionId).Send("Some Context"); because i didn't want to employer see a notification for him/her self that says you loged in.So i exclude the employer id(Contex.ConnectionId) from the target group and in this project it works.


I tried `Clients.Group("Employers").Send("Some Context");` in windows service project but result is same. Its like don t triggers at all.

Comment: i don't use `hubContext` , i send parameters from client side to hub with querystring

`var hubConnection = new HubConnection(url, querystring);
                IHubProxy _hub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("HubClassName");
                hubConnection.Start().Wait();
                _hub.Invoke("methodName");`

 and i use those parameters(`Context.QueryString["parameter"]`) for my operations, which is adding people to groups

 `Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);`

and sending notifications

`Clients.Group("Employers", Context.ConnectionId).Send("Some Context");`

Comment: If you put in a breakpoint at this line does it get here without error?  Clients.Group("Employers", Context.ConnectionId).Send("Some Context");  Or does it just continue and no error is generated?

Comment: I would recommend turning on debugging in SignalR and seeing if that helps determine why your client cannot call the server hub in this case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting